# How to make CLion auto format C++ code with Google code style, and pass the google cpplint check

Tags: c++, clion

I need to auto format my C++ code with google code style, and pass the cpplint check.

I have used  +  + L to auto format my code in CLion, but the code after format still not follow the google code style.

And I installed the CLion-cpplint plugin, this plugin only tell me where it does not follow the style. But I need a tool to auto format it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the root of your project create the file with the name `.clang-format` and the line
   `BasedOnStyle: Google` inside
2. Turn on ClangFormat as default formatter [image: ClangFormat as default formatter]
3. In Git-commit dialog add `Reformat code` action [image: <code>Reformat code</code> action]